# Why does Camera.transform.Rotate(X, Y, 0) change Z?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to rotate a camera using a joystick.
The camera should rotate up and down and left and right, but it should not rotate around z.

I have tried the following lines:

```
        float speed = 3.0f;
        float yRotation = speed * fY;
        float xRotation = speed * fX;

        camera.transform.Rotate(-yRotation, xRotation, 0.0f);
```

It seems to work, but after a few joystick movements, I can see that the camera rotation's z-value has changed, and it looks like this:

[image]

Does anybody see an obvious mistake in my code, or is the problem located somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's how to do it, I have to use eulerAngles:

```
        yaw += speedH * fX;
        pitch -= speedV * fY;
        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -20, 30);
        camera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
```